# String to double to float inaccurate precision

Tags: c#

```
string sfps = "29970";
double fps = (float)(Convert.ToDecimal(sfps)/1000);
label1.Text = fps;
```

Why does this come out as `29.969999313354492`?

`29970/1000` is only `29.97` so surely a float has enough precision to hold this value.

Comment: it is because float can not represent 29.97 exactly.

Comment: You mean "string to decimal to float [to double]". `ToDecimal` converts to the `Decimal` type, not `Double` or `Single` (aka float).

Comment: If the 29.97 you're referring to is the 29.97 common to broadcast video standards, then it is by definition precisely the rational number: 30000/1001 and you can store it as a rational number (pair of integers - numerator and denominator) instead, if you wish.

Comment: and why on earth do you truncate it to `float` precision then convert back to `double`?

Comment: Yes, `float` has a lot more precision than just two places. But remember: these are binary 1 & 0 places. It doesn't perfectly convert to/from decimal. To understand why, think about writing two thirds (2/3) as a decimal value. **You can't.** We can only put so many 6's after the decimal point before we eventually have to round to a 7 and call it good. Similarly, in binary, 1/10th ends up with a repeating pattern. _There are many more values like this_, and in fact it comes up even more often in binary since there are only two options at each decimal place instead of 10.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: I know the whole code is nonsensical, but I have been seeing these long numbers for a while and I looked at the code and noticed it was doing improper casting but I never could understand why it didn't work regardless.

Comment: simply because floating-point numbers are based on powers of `2`. 29.79 simply cannot be represented as any power of 2.

Comment: Thanks Wyck, that second article is pretty good.

Comment: @Tony Ha, I'm the third answer in that link :)

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain I think you meant "sums of powers of 2".  It's fun to try though:  `2^4 + 2^3 + 2^2 + 2^0 + 2^-1 + 2^-2 + 2^-3 + 2^-4 + 2^-5 + 2^-10 + 2^-12` ...

Comment: @IanBoyd Why did you add this information to the question? It does not improve the quality of the question. It might be part of an answer to this question, but as this question is closed and the duplicate adequately answers this question, this edit is completely pointless.

Comment: Because i'm here to make Stackoverflow a better place. Because [every question in Stack Overflow is like the Wikipedia article for some extremely narrow, specific programming question. There are lots of good ways to edit things. You can improve spelling, grammar, and even copy edit any question or answer to make it better. Anything you can do to clarify, explain, or improve the question or the answer will be a public service](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2008/09/15/stack-overflow-launches/) Because anything we can do to clairify, explain, or improve the question is a public service.

Comment: @IanBoyd But you *didn't* clarify or otherwise improve the question.  You added some irrelevant information that *detracts* from the quality of the question.

Comment: @Servy Disagree.